# okhttp3 causing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in java maven project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, okhttp

I know that there's a lot of question related to this issue but none made sense for me. I built a Java Desktop application that adds products for sale by communicating with an API. I am using okhttp 3.9.0 to accomplish this task. The problem is that my app works just fine when I execute the Netbeans' "run project" command but when I use the "java -jar file.jar" command to run the app I get exceptions stating that okhttp3 classes weren't found. That's the first time I try to run a Java application outside of an IDE so I kind of lost.

I am running my app from:

```
 C:\Users\Diego Alves\.m2\repository\com\mycompany\loja\1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Also, something that bugs me is that when searching for okhttp3 I generally end up on an Android-related page. Isn't okhttp3 used for desktop apps?

Comment: You probably want to do some research into how executable jars are packaged and how the classpath of an executable jar is managed. Netbeans (and Maven) will hide all that valuable knowledge from you, but as long as you don't know the bare basics of the Java platform you're going to keep running into problems of tools not doing what you want simply because you don't know where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **add dependencies to your jar**(okhttp is one of them) so that the JVM can find them in your classpath. To do that, in **pom.xml** add the following **plugin**:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>your.package.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Also make sure you have set `<packaging>jar</packaging>`

Then run the build (`mvn clean install`), it will generate a jar that can be executed successfully.

```
java -jar target/your_jar_name.jar
```

For **OkHTTP** there is no link with android, you can use it in any Java Application.

Comment: okhttp is quite popular in mobile development, that would explain the many search results in that area.

Comment: Have you replaced  <mainClass>your.package.MainClass</mainClass> with a class containing main method ?